# Get modal input in same view Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a modal when click on a row of my list. My modal have an input. I want to get that input value for my AJAX in Jquery.

Here is my modal:

```
<!--Reset Password Modal-->
<div id="resetModal-{{ $item['id'] }}" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Đổi mật khẩu tài khoản Brand Portal</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="block-1">
                    <label>Tài khoản:</label>
                    <label>{{ $item['email'] }}</label><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="block-2">
                    <label>Tự động sinh mật khẩu tự động</label>
                    <label class="switch">
                        <input type="checkbox">
                        <span class="slider round"></span>
                    </label>
                    <br><br>
                    <div class="text-container">
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="password">
                        <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw ... toggle-password"></span>
                    </div>
                    <br><br>
                </div>
                <label class="text">Yêu cầu đổi mật khẩu lần đăng<br> nhập tiếp theo</label>
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Hủy</button>
                <a href="/" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" name="reset-btn">Tạo mật khẩu mới</a>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $item['id'] }}">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In Js file, I tried to get that input by:

```
$("reset-btn").click(function() {
  password = $("#password").val();
  console.log(password);
});
```

But it's not working.

How I can do that? Thank you very much!

Comment: You simply don't have your selector right - you could use the name by using a selector like `$(a[name="reset-btn"])` ([jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)). Another option is to give the button an id (say `reset`, and then specify the selector like `$(#reset)` ([jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)).

Comment: thanks for your help. I fixed and it's worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add id attribute into reset button:

```
<a href="/" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" name="reset-btn" id="reset-btn">Tạo mật khẩu mới</a>
```

Then in script js:

```
$("#reset-btn").click(function() {
    password = $("#password").val();
    console.log(password);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

To execute javascript code on click of anchor link your `href` should have either `#` or `javascript:` as value.

So replace your `href` with

```
<a href="javascript:" class="btn btn-xs btn-info pull-right" name="reset-btn" id="reset-btn">Tạo mật khẩu mới</a>
```

And then use below javascript code

```
 $("#reset-btn").click(function() {
      password = $("#password").val();
      console.log(password);
    });
```

Comment: as per the question, he is trying to add click event on anchor tag, please check question

Comment: Yes he is - that part of your answer, and the other answer here made 2 hours before yours, and my comment on the question, all describe how to fix that. However, as I said above, adding the href as you described is wrong.